# Show spinner while datataables builds/init dataTable

Tags: jquery, html, datatables

so I'm using datatables to format a table generated by Coldfusion. So the tables get generated first to html (say it would have been done using PHP to make this easier)

```
<table id="table" class="table table-bordered" style="width:100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            ...
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            ...
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<script>
    $(document).ready(()=>{
        $("#table").dataTable({scrollY: 500})
    })
</script>
```

but this table is like 10000 - 15000 records and datatables takes a bit of time before it eventually formats it. I have an overlay loader/spinner in the page. Now how do i show the spinner and hide it when datatables is done creating/formatting the table? I tried a bunch of  datatables' callbacks like `initComplete` callback like this

```
$(".load-overlay").show()
$('#table').dataTable({scrollY: 500,
    "initComplete": function(settings, json) {
        $(".load-overlay").hide();
      }
});
```

but this did not work since the spinner showed briefly and was hidden before dataTables built the DataTable.

Comment: xy question, why do you load 10-15k of records?

Comment: The spinner doesn't display as intended because you're not using async logic to load the data, it's all done synchronously as the rows are part of the HTML when the page loads. The quick and dirty fix for this is to put the `dataTable()` call in a `setTimeout()` with a 20ms delay. The better fix for this is to change your dataTables implementation to read all data from the server in pages via AJAX.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I have Implemented your suggestion of `setTimeout()` I was just curious if there isn't a much better `dataTables` way because this table's size is unpredictable and I wouldn't want to guess the duration of the timeout. I also tried `setInterval` to check every 100th of a second to check if the datatable has been build yet then clear it which seems to work fine, just wanted to see if there isn't already an in-built function for this

Comment: The `20ms` timeout is not based on the size of the table.

Comment: @SASSY_ROG as @freedomn-m says, the delay isn't relevant to the size of the table, it's to force the logic to run asynchronously as the DT is drawn. Do not use `setInterval()` for this. There is no built in way to do what you require, primarily because you shouldn't have 10,000 records in a single table, let alone 15,000. The better approach is to load the data from the server side in paged 'chunks' via AJAX. DT is setup to work in this way already: https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/ajax

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The comments above about loading the table via ajax are accurate. It does take DT quite a while to initialize a large table, and making the browser load the whole thing into the DOM before initializing DT on top of it is really slow and not great UX.

You can convert the table to use an [ajax](https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/ajax) data source, which is faster than directly loading it as you are. This will load the entire dataset as a JSON blob in the background, and only render the number of rows selected by the user. This works fine until you get to really large datasets, and loading the massive JSON blob becomes its own performance hit. At that point, you want to look at [server side processing](https://datatables.net/examples/server_side/index.html). It's more challenging to implement, because you must handle all of the searching (as well as sorting) as part of your data query, but it allows you to only load 10/25/50 records at a time, which makes it *much* faster. With either of these options, DataTables will display its own "loading" message.

Now, suppose you're working with a small enough dataset, or for some reason you really need to load the entire table at once. This is what I've done to make it hide the table until it's ready:

First, hide the datatable by default, and show a spinner in its place:

```
<table id="datatable" style="display:none">...</table>
<div id="dt_loader" class="spinner"></div>
```

Then, in your JS, once you've called DataTable(), hide the spinner and show the table:

```
$('#dataTable').DataTable(options);
$('div#dt_loader').hide();
$('#dataTable').show();
```

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: table.show is not a function.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I updated the snippet. I'd removed the code that made dataTable a jQuery object, not realizing I was treating as such in this snippet.